# how to compare column A of two different workbooks excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have two differents workbooks and I want to compare the first column (A) of the two workbooks ,and getting added things in a List box( things that they don't exist in column A of workbook 1 sheet 1 ) . I have written a code and the my problem is that I my code compare do not compare right things . I would be very happy if someone could help me.

```
Sub Bouton1_Cliquer()


Dim i As Long, lastA As Long, lastB As Long

Dim compare As Variant

Range("A:A").ClearFormats

Dim sh1 As Worksheet

Dim wkb As Workbook

Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ZAGLIZ\Documents\Classeur1.xltm")

Set sh1 = wkb.Sheets("Feuil1")

lastA = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

lastB = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastA

    compare = Application.Match(Range("A" & i), sh1.Range("B2" & lastB), 0)

        If IsError(compare) Then

 UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "Libellé : " & Range("A" & i) & "  du montant  " & 

Range("C" & i) & " est ajouté !"

        End If
Next i

UserForm1.Show

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use a little more clarity in the question as the description and code seem a little contradictory and 'do not compare right things isn't really descriptive enough of the problem. Are you comparing column a in both sheets as per the description or column a to column b as per the code? I will try to provide an answer to get you there anyway:

-Specifically declare and utilize names for both the books/sheets you want to work with, you just refer to range a number of times which is ambiguous when working between sheets and may be causing problems depending where your button is located

-`sh1.Range("B2" & lastB)` is not doing what you think, it should be `sh1.Range("B2:B" & lastB)` (if it is supposed to be column b)

-This will only check 'one-way' and it is not clear from your question whether this is what you intend/it is checking for missing values in the right sheet. You may need a second match to check for things that aren't present the other way around, or you may want to switch the logic to check the other sheet instead

Edit: Based on your comment try the code below, put it in a module and call the procedure name from your button click event to prevent the ambiguity, I've changed some of the declared names as they were confusing to the purpose:

```
Sub ImInAModule()

Dim i As Long, Sheet1Last As Long, Sheet2Last As Long

Dim compare As Variant

Dim origBook As Workbook

Dim checkBook As Workbook

Set origBook = ActiveWorkbook

origBook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").ClearFormats

Set checkBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ZAGLIZ\Documents\Classeur1.xltm")

Sheet1Last = origBook.Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Sheet2Last = checkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Sheet1Last

compare = Application.Match(origBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i), checkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & Sheet2Last), 0)

    If IsError(compare) Then
UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "Libellé : " & origBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i) & " du montant " & origBook.Sheets(1).Range("C" & i) & " est ajouté !"

    End If
Next i

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I want to compare column a in both sheets .and this two sheets are in differents workbooks .and I need to see added things (means things that they don't exist in shheet 1, and they exist in sheet 2) .

Comment: Ok see my Edit, this is checking that everything exists from your original sheet (with the button in it) in the other sheet you're loading and where it doesn't adding to your list.